# Disabling ApplicationBarIconButton in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've two **applicationbariconbuttons**, out of which one is to be enabled only if certain conditions are met. My Code in C#

```
if (//conditions)
  {
     ((ApplicationBarIconButton)DeleteButton).IsEnabled = false;
  }
```

But while excecution, i get the following error,

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
```

Help me to solve this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you calling this method with reflection? Post the code calling this and full stacktrace, innerexception etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventhough we can keep name for the application bar icon button, we can not disable or enable it using the name given in **x:Name=""**.
So use the follwoing code,

```
((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[index]).IsEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use like that

```
 ApplicationBarIconButton myAppIconButton = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];

 myAppIconButton .IsEnabled = false;
```

And you will disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Application bar buttons are stored in a list you would have to call it by referring to a particular item like this.

((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IsEnabled = false;

This would solve the purpose.